# What are Drupal Apps?

Tags: features

I've been seeing the use of [Apps](http://drupal.org/project/apps). What are drupal apps?

Are they just glorified [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) with a backend UI? What are the differences between the two on a lower level? The apps project page only gives a pretty high level understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the Open App Standard http://groups.drupal.org/open-app-standard/oas ? Here's an excerpt that might help:

> What is an app? Before we say what an App is it’s helpful to know who
>   it’s for: An App is for the end user, typically a non-technical user
>   of a Drupal site such as the site administrator....
>
> ...Technically, an App is a collection of new or existing Drupal
>   functionality, including Modules, Features, and Themes along with some
>   simple additional code that publishes the existence of the App to the
>   rest of the App infrastructure.
>
> What distinguishes an App from a Module or Feature is that the App
>   includes all of the additional polish, end-user UI, configuration UI,
>   sample content, and documentation that are needed to fully meet a
>   specific need. Whereas Modules and Features are more developer-centric
>   and provide building blocks for larger functionality, Apps are larger
>   blocks of completed functionality.

Comment: So an app is almost like an install profile, but you can install several apps to a single site?